# Azure B2C Setting a Customer Policy with auto generated Username for Signup

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, policy

So I am trying out Azure B2C to see what the pros / cons are of the service.

Basically as a use case I want users to sign up with their email address but have an auto generated username that they will use to sign in.

I have set the local signin to use username so sign in works correctly. But during the signup process the username field appears and allows the user to input a desired username.

Is there a way, perhaps through custom policies, to automatically set the username field to a value (incremented from user ids column) and not allow the user to update this value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by the "user ID" column? Do you have an external database containing these?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so soon. So Azure ad b2c has its own user db so the user id would be the username someone enters during registration. This is the field I wish to automatically populate.

Comment: I came across the Azure Graph API for adding users etc, wondering if this would beneficial for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to prefix the username field during the signup process and apply a pattern to ensure the user enters a number after the prefix which should be good enough for the use case